# deleting outlier in r with account of nominal var

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, mean, outliers

Say, i have three columns

```
x <- c(-10, 1:6, 50)
x1<- c(-20, 1:6, 60)
z<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

check outliers for x

```
bx <- boxplot(x)
bx$out
```

check outliers for x1

```
bx1 <- boxplot(x1)
bx1$out
```

now we must delete outliers

```
x <- x[!(x %in% bx$out)]
x

x1 <- x1[!(x1 %in% bx1$out)]
x1
```

but we have variable Z(nominal) and we must remove observations, which correspond to the outlier of variables x and x1,
in our case it is 1 and 8 obs. of Z

How to do it?
in output we must have

```
x   x1  z
Na  Na  Na
1   1   2
2   2   3
3   3   4
4   4   5
5   5   6
6   6   7
Na  Na  Na
```

Comment: Hi, you are using my solution as I can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50584209/number-of-rows-of-result-is-not-a-multiple-of-vector-length-arg-2-in-r/50584486#50584486 Acceptance of the answer is welcome! See you on the other question.

Comment: @Terru_theTerror, yes, you are right, how can we decide the problem of different lenght. Can you fix your solution with accounting of different leght.

Comment: I'm trying to help you on the other topic. If this question is solved, close it accepting an answer.

Comment: @Terru_theTerror, i accepted your answer, but now i edited new post. Can you check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
x_to_remove<-which(x %in% bx$out)
x <- x[!(x %in% bx$out)]

x1_to_remove<-which(x1 %in% bx1$out)
x1 <- x1[!(x1 %in% bx1$out)]

z<-z[-unique(c(x_to_remove,x1_to_remove))]
z    
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Before delete values in `x` and `x1` you have to save the positions (`x_to_remove` and `x1_to_remove`) and than use to clean `z`.

Your output:

```
data.frame(cbind(x,x1,z))
  x x1 z
1 1  1 2
2 2  2 3
3 3  3 4
4 4  4 5
5 5  5 6
6 6  6 7
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dataframe as

```
x  <- c(-10, 1:6, 50)
x1 <- c(-20, 1:6, 60)
z  <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
df <- data.frame(x = x, x1 = x1, z = z)
```

You can do this to remove rows with outliers in `x` or `x1`

```
is.outlier <- sapply(df[c('x', 'x1')], function(x) x %in% boxplot(x)$out)
df[!rowSums(is.outlier),]

#   x x1 z
# 2 1  1 2
# 3 2  2 3
# 4 3  3 4
# 5 4  4 5
# 6 5  5 6
# 7 6  6 7
```

In `tidyverse` (same result)

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  filter(map(list(x, x1), ~!.x %in% boxplot(.x)$out) %>% pmap_lgl(`&`))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
z[!((x1 %in% bx1$out) | (x %in% bx$out))]
```

Or a `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x, x1, z) %>% 
  select(starts_with("x")) %>%  
  map_dfr(~.x %in% boxplot(.x, plot = F)$out) %>%  
  with(.,!rowSums(.)) %>% 
  filter(df, .)
   x x1 z
1 50  1 2
2  1  2 3
3  2  3 4
4  3  4 5
5  4  5 6
6  5  6 7
```